# ElGamal same private and random key attack

Tags: cryptography

I'm having difficulty understanding this.

Consider two messages are encrypted using the same cyclic group order $q$, generator $g$, private key $x$, and random parameter $y$.
The attacker knows a plaintext $m_1$ and its corresponding ciphertext $c_1=\left(r_1,s_1\right)$.

I was told that, under these circumstances, if an attacker **also** knows the ciphertext $c_2=\left(r_2,s_2\right)$ of another message $m_2$, they can recover $m_2$.

How is this possible? Wouldn't the attacker need to know $q$ and $g$?

Comment: [cross-posted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/99901/18298).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key in ElGamal encryption is $(G, q, g, g^x)$ and the secret key is $x$. Here, $G$ is a cyclic group of order $q$, with generator $g$, and $x$ is a random value between $1$ and $q-1$.

Given the assumption, the attacker knows a message $m_1$ as well as two ciphertexts: $c_1 = (r_1, s_1) = (g^y, m_1 \cdot g^{xy})$ and $c_2 = (r_2, s_2) = (g^y, m_2 \cdot g^{xy})$. Using only $m_1, s_1$, and $s_2$, the attacker can recover $m_2$ as follows: $$\begin{align*} m_2 &= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot m_2 \\
&= (m_1 \cdot m_1^{-1}) \cdot (g^{-xy} \cdot g^{xy}) \cdot m_2 \\
&= m_1 \cdot (m_1^{-1} \cdot g^{-xy}) \cdot (g^{xy} \cdot m_2) \\
&= m_1 \cdot s_1^{-1} \cdot s_2\end{align*}$$

In the final step, we used the fact that multiplication in a cyclic group is commutative. The attacker knows the public key, in particular $q$ and $g$, so they can efficiently perform multiplication and compute inverses in $G$.

Comment: What about if modulo is involved?

Comment: You need to be able to perform multiplication and take inverses as part of encryption / decryption. The attacker only needs these two things to recover $m_2$. This is true no matter what cyclic group $G$ is used, in particular it could involve multiplication modulo $N$.

Comment: Would you mind showing more steps? For example, how did you derive $m_1 \cdot (m_1^{-1} \cdot g^{-xy})$?

Comment: I edited my response to show more steps, hope this helps.